# Need Linq equivalent

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Help in find the Linq equivalent on the below sql query:

```
select sum(weight) from (
select weight from pers p
join list l on l.persindex= p.persindex
group by  p.persindex,weight) a
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want ..

Comment: i have updated my answer with vb.net version have look to it...

Answer (score 0):

```
from p in context.pers  
join l in context.list on l.persindex equals p.persindex 
group by new 
{      p.persindex,
       l.weight 
} into myGroup  
select new()
{      Key = myGroup.Key,
       GroupSum = myGroup.sum(x=>x.weight)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you need:

```
public int CalcWeight(IEnumerable<Person> pers, IEnumerable<Person> list)
{
    return  
        pers
        .Join(list, p=>p.PersIndex, l=>l.PersIndex, (p, l) => new {p.PersIndex, l.Weight})
        .GroupBy( a => new {a.PersIndex, a.Weight})
        .Sum(group=>group.Key.Weight);
}
```

Data class Person is decalerd like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersIndex;
    public int Weight;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**VB.NET version**

```
Dim customerList = From p In pers
                   Group Join l In list On 
                     p.persindex Equals l.persindex
                   Into joineddata = Group, 
                        TotalOweight = Sum(p.weight) 
                   Select p.persindex, TotalOweight
```

---

Try : [Linquer SQL to LINQ convertion tool](http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads) :   [image]

```
from p in pers 
joins l in list on  l.persindex equals p.persindex
group by new {p.persindex,l.weight } into grp
select new { sum = grp.sum(x=>x.weight)}
```

Comment: I am using this in vb.net. Is it different for vb.net?

Comment: Below is the query I am using now, which skips some values(Same weight)
Double = (From p In pers Join l In List On p("persindex") Equals l("persindex") Select CDbl(p("Weight"))).Distinct.Sum()
I tried you query but getting error on TotalOweight = Sum(p.weight)

Comment: @user1451208 - now i m confuse what you actually want.........not getting you at all